# can you read images to ftp?

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, axios

Here is the code to api class exec

```
async CRUDPersonal({ state, dispatch }) {
    try {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("Password", JSON.stringify(state.InputPassword.Password));
      formData.append("CRUDPersonnel", JSON.stringify(state.InputPersonnel));
      formData.append("Type", JSON.stringify(state.Personnel.type));
      formData.append("CheckBox", JSON.stringify(state.Personnel_checkBox));
      // formData.append("temp_doc_file", JSON.stringify(state.temp_doc_file));
      formData.append("fileImage", state.PersonnelImage.fileImage);
      const response = await window.Axios.post(
        `${window.api}exec/CRUDPersonnel/`,
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      );
      await window.Swal.fire({
        position: "center",
        icon: response.data.type,
        title: response.data.alert,
        text: response.data.text,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 2000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
      });
      if (response.data.type == "success")
        await dispatch("ActionRead2/R_GET_Personnel", null, { root: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
}
```

class exec function CRUDPersonnel

```
    public function CRUDPersonnel()
    {
        print_r($_FILES['fileImage']);
        $ftp_server = "192.168.1.240";
        $ftp_username = "Tea_picture";
        $ftp_password = "WeblannaTea_Pic";
        $ftp_port = 2121;
        $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_port, 90) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
        ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);
    
        $local_file = 'test.txt';
        $remote_file = '/image'; 
        if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
            echo "อัปโหลดเรียบร้อยแล้ว $local_file.";
        } else {
            echo "เกิดข้อผิดพลาดในการอัปโหลด $local_file.\n";
            echo error_get_last()["message"] . "\n";
        }
    }
```

result

```
Array
(
    [name] => asdsad45645678.jpg
    [type] => 
    [tmp_name] => 
    [error] => 6
    [size] => 0
)
```

เกิดข้อผิดพลาดในการอัปโหลด test.txt.
ftp_put(test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Now I'm having trouble uploading images to ftp and I'm wondering why tmp_name is empty. I have tried many ways but it is not working. Please help me to solve this problem for me.

Comment: Seems like your real question is why Axios isn't uploading your file from the browser to the PHP script - which of course has nothing to do with FTP